# Implement Opensea Operator Filter Registry

Tags: solidity, nft, opensea

In order to enforce creators fees over NFT contracts Opensea request that you implement the [Operator Filter Registry](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/operator-filter-registry). According to [the documentation](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/operator-filter-registry#default-usage) you should override the following methods:

```
setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved)
approve(address operator, uint256 tokenId)
transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory data)
```

It seems that overriding the first 2 (`setApprovalForAll` and `approve`) should be enough to enforce it, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One scenario that comes to mind is that someone could use an ERC-721 token [with `permit` functionality](https://soliditydeveloper.com/erc721-permit) and change the allowances without calling the `setApprovalForAll` or `approve` functions.

Comment: Nice! Maybe you also have an idea why not override only the last 3 methods?

Comment: The spender of the coins could send the tokens to another contract (not themselves) - for example to a Vault contract. In the `transferFrom` function https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L158-L163 msg.sender would be unequal to `_to`

Comment: If the `transferFrom` method has the `onlyAllowedOperator` modifier the msg.sender has to be either the owner or an allowed operator. Can't see why it's not enough

Comment: Good point. I guess the tried to be more explicit then.